# Angular 2 - Pipe cannot be found

Tags: angular, angular2-pipe

I'm trying to use my custom pipe with an array which I assign values to within a subscribe. However I get this error:

```
Unhandled Promise rejection: Template parse errors:
The pipe 'summary' could not be found
```

**app.module.ts**

```
import { NgModule }      from '@angular/core';
import { BrowserModule } from '@angular/platform-browser';
import { FormsModule } from '@angular/forms'
import { HttpModule } from '@angular/http'
import { AppComponent }  from './app.component';
import { UserComponent }  from './components/user.component';
import { AboutComponent }  from './components/about.component';
import { routing }  from './app.routing';
import { SummaryPipe } from './pipes/summary.pipe'

@NgModule({
  imports:      [ BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpModule, routing ],
  declarations: [ AppComponent, UserComponent, AboutComponent, SummaryPipe ],
  bootstrap:    [ AppComponent ]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

**summary.pipe.ts**

```
import { Pipe, PipeTransform } from '@angular/core'

@Pipe({name: 'summary'})
export class SummaryPipe implements PipeTransform{
    transform(value: string, args: String[]){
        if(value)
            return value.substring(0, 50) + "...";
    }
}
```

**user.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { PostsService } from '../services/posts.services';

@Component({
    moduleId: module.id,
    selector: 'user',
    templateUrl: 'user.component.html',
    providers: [PostsService],

})
export class UserComponent  { 
  name: String;
  email: string;
  address: address;
  hobbies: string[];
  showHobbies: boolean;
  posts: Post[];

  constructor(private postsService: PostsService){
    this.name = 'John Doe';
    this.email = 'john@gmail.com';
    this.address = {
        street: '12 Main st',
        city: 'Boston',
        state: 'MA'
  }
  this.hobbies = ['Music', 'Movies', 'Sports']
  this.showHobbies = false;

  this.postsService.getPosts().subscribe(posts => {
      this.posts = posts;
  })

 }

  toggleHobbies(){
     if(this.showHobbies)
     this.showHobbies = false;
     else
     this.showHobbies = true;
 }

 addHobby(hobby){
     this.hobbies.push(hobby);
 }

 deleteHobby(index){
     this.hobbies.splice(index, 1);
 }
}

 interface address{
     street: string;
     city: string;
     state: string;
 }

interface Post{
    id: number;
    title: string;
    body: string;
}
```

**user.component.html**

```
<h3>Posts</h3>
    <div  *ngFor="let post of posts">
        <h3>{{post.title }}</h3>
        <p>{{post.body | summary}}</p>
    </div>
```

I've followed the documentation but I can't seem to get it to work. Any ideas?

Comment: Although everything seems good and strange you are facing such an issue, could you try using the summary like `{{post.body | summary: null}}` (although that doesn't makes any sense)

Comment: @AliBaig Yeah I'm a bit stuck. I tried using summary pipe on another interpolation on the same page and I still get the same error. I don't understand what I'm missing.

Comment: Maybe stupid, but gotta ask... have you checked that the import path is correct to your module, of course your ide would complain if you have the wrong path. Asking, cuz, could not reproduce your issue with your code and static data... http://plnkr.co/edit/ZT4DcWFqb6SxHL9tGoTS

Comment: @AJT_82 I believe it's correct because I'm using visual studio code and I get a red squiggly if it's not pointing in the right directory.

Comment: @nickgowdy Yeah, then it's correct. Just had to ask tho, since couldn't find anything wrong with your code. Hmm. Strange error.

Comment: And if you remove the pipe from the template, all works like it should?

Comment: Could you try renaming summary to something else for testing purposes to see if the error changes (again something that doesn't makes any sense but still have to try something)

Comment: @AJT_82 Yeah as soon as I removed the pipe it works. It's so strange, I can't get a basic version of my custom pipe to work. I've removed a lot of the code so the page is really simple and it still doesn't work.

Comment: @AJT_82 I've made another pipe called welcome and it's the same problem. It always says promise rejection in the console.

Comment: @nickgowdy ... well this seems just utterly strange. Could you try and reproduce the issue in a plunker? Can't really come up with any more reasons as to why your pipes aren't working.

Comment: Hey guys, this is going to sound really stupid but I think the problem was the naming convention. I started a brand new project with angular-quickstart and I got it to work. I noticed when I referenced the pipe at the app module leve, I didn't call it './app.summary.pipe'. As as I did that change it worked. I've spent a good couple of hours looking at it so hopefully if anyone gets stuck that might help.

Comment: transform function decleration should return some value. In your case string

Comment: @nickgowdy yeah, pipes do not get inherited, you need to declare the pipe in that module you are using it, I didn't bring this up, because I thought it wouldn't be a problem, since by the code (ngModule) you provided it is correct, i.e, you seem to have just one ngModule and have decalared the pipe where you have declared the components that use the pipe :)

Answer (score 0):

transform function decleration should return some value. In your case string.

And transform function should look like that:

```
  transform(value: string): string {
     if(value){
        return value.substring(0, 50) + "...";
     }
     return value;
  }
```

Comment: Maybe you missed my plunker, but there should not be anything wrong with the pipe as is: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZT4DcWFqb6SxHL9tGoTS?p=info